# Moving tab focus to another NSWindow's view then back again

Tags: cocoa, focus

Have a borderless window over NSTextField with a NSButton in that window. canBecomeKeyView returns YES for this NSButton. I want to be able to emulate setNextKeyView for this NSButton to be the next focus holder after NSTextField. The borderless window is the child window of the main window. The NSTextField resides on main window. What is the proper way of doing this thing?

Comment: Have you tried calling `setNextKeyView` in order to set this up?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I've also tried to setInitialFirstResponder: for the child window to my NSButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem.

In interface builder I had a window with an NSTextField and an NSButton. I want to be able to tab between them. I did what I thought was correct:

- Set the intialFirstResponser for the NSWindow to be my NSTextField
- Set the NSTextField nextKeyView to be the NSButton
- Set the NSButton nextKeyView to be my NSTextField

But this was not working as expected.

It Turns out that in the Apple > System Preferences > Keyboard there is a setting that allows you to press Tab to move keyboard focus between:

- Text boxes and lists only
- All controls

The first option is set by default. Once changed to All controls everything worked as expected.

Comment: I am facing same issue. **Did you get any solution?** nextKeyView is set properly between two NSTextField. but issue is with NSButton and NSTextField tab index.